# Permission denied for PHP application with xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, permissions, xampp

I am trying to make my first php based website and have ran into a problem. The website is very basic and is intended to allow users to enter student information into a database. I built this website following a tutorial by Derek Banas which can be found here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpQts3ezPVg&t=25s.

Whenever I try to open my getStudentInfo.php file in my browser, I receive the following error:

> Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\practiceWebDev): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\practiceWebDev\practicePHPmySQL\getStudentInfo.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../practiceWebDev' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\practiceWebDev\practicePHPmySQL\getStudentInfo.php on line 3

Does this error mean I have something wrong with my code? Or do I need to change the php.ini or httpd.conf files associated with XAMPP? Below are the files I have dealing with connections if they are of any use. Thank you very much for any feedback you all can give. Also, I make use of mysql for my database.

**mysqli_connect.php:**

```
<?php
//IMPORTANT! This file must be saved outside of where the rest of my files related to our website are saved so that no one may access them.

DEFINE ('DB_USER' 'studentweb');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD' 'turtledove');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST' 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME' 'studentdatabase');

$databaseConnection = @mysqli_connect(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_NAME)
//using the above @ symbol before mysqli_connect makes it so errors will not appear in the browser.
//@ is known as the 'error control operator', and makes PHP suppress error messages associated with the expression.
OR die('Could not connect to MySql lol' . mysqli_connect_error());
//mysqli_connect_error() is a function defined in the php synthax.
?>
```

**getStudentInfo.php:**

```
<?php
//now we require the file outside of the current directory called mysqli_connect.php
require_once('../../practiceWebDev');

//the query below will display the information from each student in the form of a table.
$query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, street, province,
          postal_code, phone_num, birth_date, sex, date_entered,
          lunch_cost, student_id, FROM students";

//the response below is all the info that we've gotten that we want to show in our table.
$response = @mysqli_query($databseConnection, $query);

//below we will see if the query executed properly.
if($response)
{
    echo '<table align="left"   cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">
        <tr><td align="left"><b>First Name</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Last Name</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Email</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Street</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>City</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>State</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Zip</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Phone</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Birth Day</b></td></tr>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td align=left">'.$row['first_name'].'</td><td align="left">'.$row['last_name'].'</td><td align="left">'.$row['email'].'</td>';
        echo '<td align="left">'.$row['street'].'</td><td align="left">'.$row['city'].'</td><td align="left">'.$row['state'].'</td>';
        echo '<td align="left">'.$row['zip'].'</td><td align="left">'.$row['phone'].'</td><td align="left">'.$row['birth_date'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

}
else
{
    echo "Couldn't issue database query";
    echo mysqli_error($databseConnection);
}

mysqli_close($databseConnection);
?>
```

**studentadded.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add Student</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--First, we need to check if this page was actually reached when the form was submitted--->
<?php
//Below we check that a POST operation was completed by the button I have named "submitButton"
if(isset($_POST['submitButton']))
{
    $data_missing = array();
    /*If there is an empty field when a POST operation is completed, that field's name will be
      added to the data_missing array so that we may visually see which fields are not being sent*/
    if(empty($_POST['first_name']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'First Name';
    }
    else
    {
        $f_name = trim($POST['first_name']);
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['lastName']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'Last Name';
    }
    else
    {
        $l_name = trim($POST['lastName']);
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'email';
    }
    else
    {
        $email = trim($POST['email']);
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['street']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'street';
    }
    else
    {
        $street = trim($POST['street']);
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['province']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'province';
    }
    else
    {
        $province = trim($POST['province']);
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['postal_code']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'postal_code';
    }
    else
    {
        $postal_code = trim($POST['postal_code']);
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['phone_num']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'phone_num';
    }
    else
    {
        $phone_num = trim($POST['phone_num']);
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['birth_date']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'birth_date';
    }
    else
    {
        $birth_date = trim($POST['birth_date']);
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['sex']))
    {
        $sex[] = 'sex';
    }
    else
    {
        $sex = trim($POST['sex']);
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['lunch_cost']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'lunch_cost';
    }
    else
    {
        $lunch_cost = trim($POST['lunch_cost']);
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['student_id']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'student_id';
    }
    else
    {
        $student_id = trim($POST['student_id']);
    }
    
    //Now lets check
    if(empty($data_missing))
    {
        require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');
        
        $myQuery = "INSERT INTO students (first_name, last_name, email, street, province,
                  postal_code, phone_num, birth_date, sex, date_entered, lunch_cost, 
                  student_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, NULL)";
                  
                  $statement = mysqli_prepare($databaseConnection, $myQuery);
                  //We have to represent the data type for each of the value that will be passed into our database.
                  /*i Integers
                  d Doubles
                  b Blobs
                  s Everything Else*/
                  
                  //Now lets bind variables to the '?'s passed in with the myQuery query.
                  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssssssisssd", $f_name, $l_name, $email, $street, $province,
                  $postal_code, $phone_num, $birth_date, $sex, $lunch_cost, $student_id);
                  
                  mysqli_statement_execute($statement);
                  
                  $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_addected_rows($statement);
                  if($affected_rows == 1)
                  {
                      echo 'Went through properly! Student entered correctly!';
                      
                      mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
                      mysqli_close($databaseConnection);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      echo 'Error occurred :(';
                      echo '<br />';
                      echo mysqli_error();
                      
                      mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
                      mysqli_close($databaseConnection);
                      
                  }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'You need to enter the following data my dude: <br />';
        foreach($data_missing as $missingData)
        {
            echo "$missingData<br />";
        }
        
    }
                  
}

?>

    <form action="http://localhost/studentadded.php" method="post">
        <b>Add a New Student</b>

        <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" size="30" value="" /></p>
        <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="30" value="" /></p>
        <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="60" value="" /></p>
        <p>Street: <input type="text" name="street" size="50" value="" /></p>
        <p>Province: <input type="text" name="province" size="3" value="" /></p>
        <p>Postal Code: <input type="text" name="postal_code" size="6" value="" /></p>
        <p>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone_num" size="20" value="" /></p>
        <p>Birth Date (YYYY-MM-DD): <input type="text" name="birth_date" size="20" value="" /></p>
        <p>Sex: <input type="text" name="sexField1" size="5" maxlength="1" value="" />
        <!---<p>Sex: <input type="radio" name="sexField" value="M" />
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="sexField" value="F" checked /></p>--->
        <!--<p>Date Entered: <input type="" name="" size="" value="" /></p>--->
        <p>Lunch Cost: <input type="text" name="lunch_cost" size="5" value="" /></p>
        <p>Student ID: <input type="text" name="student_id" size="10" value="" /></p>

        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="submitValue">
        <!-- type="submit" is a predefined term in html--->
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**addStudent.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Add Student</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost/studentadded.php" method="post">
            <b>Add a New Student</b>

            <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" size="30" value="" /></p>
            <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="30" value="" /></p>
            <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="60" value="" /></p>
            <p>Street: <input type="text" name="street" size="50" value="" /></p>
            <p>Province: <input type="text" name="province" size="3" value="" /></p>
            <p>Postal Code: <input type="text" name="postal_code" size="6" value="" /></p>
            <p>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone_num" size="20" value="" /></p>
            <p>Birth Date (YYYY-MM-DD): <input type="text" name="birth_date" size="20" value="" /></p>
            <p>Sex: <input type="text" name="sexField1" size="5" maxlength="1" value="" />
            <!---<p>Sex: <input type="radio" name="sexField" value="M" />
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexField" value="F" checked /></p>--->
            <!--<p>Date Entered: <input type="" name="" size="" value="" /></p>--->
            <p>Lunch Cost: <input type="text" name="lunch_cost" size="5" value="" /></p>
            <p>Student ID: <input type="text" name="student_id" size="10" value="" /></p>
            
            <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="submitValue">
            <!-- type="submit" is a predefined term in html--->
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried running xampp with as an administrator?

Comment: Yes I have, the errors don't change though.

Comment: I can not see any `require_once()` on the line 3 of _getStudentInfo.php_ file. Is this all of your code?

Comment: I have fixed the formatting, the `require_once()` function should be visible now.

Comment: OK, so the question is do you have this file **practiceWebDev** at the expected path or not?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the tutorial files at this address:

http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/09/php-mysql-tutorial/

In the file **getstudentinfo.php** at the beginning of the file

You should have `require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');`

But you have `require_once('../../practiceWebDev');`
(there is no filename in this line of your code!)

So I think just changing this line of code and using correct path + **the filename** should solve your error

### Update:

Again from what I can see in your code, in **studentadded.php** file you have this line of code:

```
require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');
```

So if your **studentadded.php** file is working without errors, then just change the line which is generating the error in **getstudentinfo.php** file  with this line.